# BJT amplifier modification

Tags: transistors, amplifier

[image: BJT amplifier circuit that I want to modify]

I am interested in this project and I am new to transistors and amplifiers. I have few concerns with respect to this project:

1. How to run the above given circuit with 5V instead of given 9V, what all modifications will I have to do?
2. I want to connect 2 speakers in this circuit, to have the stereo effect, how should I do that?
3. I didn't get the transistor mentioned above that is 2N3403 so the shopkeeper suggested that I take its equivalent i.e. BC337, will it work properly or do I have to change the resistors configuration?

Comment: This is the second time you posted this schematic, and you were already told last time to put component designators on it.  No, I'm not going to talk about the third resistor from the top right.  -1 for posting a unacceptable schematic, especially since you are expecting detailed answers that need to discuss the circuit, and voting to close as not enough information.  Fix it, else the close votes will keep coming.  The clock is ticking.

Comment: I know this question is about that specific circuit, but you might consider looking at this amplifier. It worked very well for me, it's louder and more efficient than most designs like the above. http://www.electroschematics.com/263/miniature-audio-amplifier/
You don't need the variable resistor, just connect your audio input directly to the cap. To use a microphone, you need a preamp. http://electrosuite.com/audio/bc547-dynamic-microphone-amplifier.html
Exact component values are rarely of consequence here. This design is more work, but well worth it.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't hesitate in downloading a free spice simulator and seeing for yourself exactly what happens. LTSpice is quite good and a lot of the major players offer free student-versions of their top product, limited usually in node or component count.

If you're serious about electronics as a hobby or job then, doing what I've said above is more important than getting an answer to your question.

Off the top of my head, it looks to me like it would still work at 5 volts but maybe a tweak to R1 (maybe take it down to 180kohm) might be in order to adjust the bias points of the two transistor. Having said that I still think it stands a good chance of working at 5V.

You can put two speakers in series but the output and input is mono so all you'll get is two speakers producing the sound instead of 1. I'd stick with 8 ohm speaker in series rather than drop to 4 ohm - it looks like it isn't ideally designed for an 8 ohm speaker given the transistors used.

I don't think using a BC337 will make much difference.